# 4 degree polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials

I have the following equation: $$\frac{(T_{max})^4+(T_{min})^4}{2}$$ The parameters $T_{max}$ and $T_{min}$ refer to maximum and minimum temperature respectively. What I want is to insert the parameter $T_{mean}$ -which is the average of the two aforementioned parameters- and create an equation without $T_{max}-T_{min}$. I have already tried some stuff but nothing works.

Can someone please help?!?
Thank you in advance!

P.S. I am sorry if the title is misleading/irrelevant.

Comment: It is not possible to express the equation purely in terms of $T_{mean}$.

Comment: You're going to have to involve the "spread" of the values in some way. It doesn't have to be literally $T_{max}-T_{min}$, but it will be something related to the difference between the values.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish is impossible. Assume that we could find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(T_{mean}) = \frac{T_{max}^4 + T_{min}^4}{2}.$$
Now take for example $T_{max} = -1$ and $T_{min} = 1$, so that $T_{mean} = 0$. We will have
$$f(0) = 1.$$
However, we could also take $T_{max} = -2$ and $T_{min} = 2$, so that $T_{mean} = 0$ again but
$$f(0) = 16,$$
giving a contradiction.

As a general rule of thumb, if you want to rewrite an expression consisting of $n$ independent variables, you will need $n$ variables again.